# rails link_to helper - supplying an onclick attribute gets rid of :remote => true (action is processed as HTML)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

So yeah as the title says, whenever I supply an onclick parameter to my link, it processes the resulting action as HTML in place of JS. Any ideas?

```
link_to "/profile/share?id=#{post.id}", :id => "share_#{post.id}", :remote => true do "stuff" end

link_to "/profile/share?id=#{post.id}", :onclick => "javascript:$('#share_#{post.id}').text('Loading...')", :id => "share_#{post.id}", :remote => true do "stuff" end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a separate script that binds your custom event handler:

```
$('a.share-link').click(function() {
    $(this).text('Loading...');
});
```

You'll need to add the '.share-link' class to all the links you want to act like that, but once you've done that it should work like you want.  This method will have jQuery (which I assume you're using, from your code sample) bind the event handler, leaving the 'onclick' attribute free for Rails to use for AJAX purposes.

Hope this helps!